# How to use a react.js component as template for html-webpack-plugin?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I was looking at html-webpack-plugin but I prefer to have a react component to render my root index.html. (easier to type, for example variables from webpack build...) plus my app is already in react, I don't need 2 ways to do templating. I'm using ts-node to run webpack build, so I have types in the config as well.

They say to provide a custom loader, but how does the loader gets the template variables like scripts urls and other stuff? (even this seems hacky, I'd prefer a simpler solution. I'm not sure why they don't allow `template` option to be a function that gets some args, and returns the html as a string)